# How to multiply a String by an Integer?

Tags: java

I know there's some way to change a string into an integer but it's not really working out for me when I try to do it.

I was asked to take in an integer 'n' and 'a' string 's' and print 's' 'n' times

Here's my code and my main question / question is how do I easily turn the string into an integer so I can multiply the two together:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
        System.out.println("Enter the number of times you want to print a string");
        Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = n.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the string you want printed");
        Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = y.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: You won't be Multiplying them.

Comment: Converting the string to an integer won't cause multiplying them to repeat the string.

Comment: oh, that's easy. xyz times 2 = 2xyz :-)

Comment: If you use Groovy language is as simple as `println 'xyz' * 2`. In Java use loop statement.

Answer (score 3):

You only need one `Scanner`, and if I understand your question then you might use a loop like, also an `int n`.

```
System.out.println("Enter the number of times you want to "
        + "print a string");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter the string you want printed");
String s = scan.nextLine();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.print(s);
}
System.out.println();
```

Of course, you could put the loop in a method like

```
private static String multiply(String str, int n) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sb.append(str);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then you could call it like,

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter the string you want printed");
String s = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println(multiply(s, n));
```

Comment: You should initialize the `StringBuilder`'s capacity to `str.length() * n`.

Comment: @August That's a micro-optimization.